# здравствуйте, подскажите где запятые ставить

Tags: запятые, деепричастный-оборот

В соответствии с Вашим поручением в ходе визита о проведении капитального ремонта

Comment: Нужно как-то завершить фразу, а пока говорить неочем.

Comment: В соответствии с Вашим поручением в ходе визита о проведении капитального ремонта кровли в здании №5

Comment: Стиль сомнительный.  Сравнить:  В Москву с официальным визитом прибыла делегация ...В ходе визита представители мэрии города подписали Совместное заявление...

Comment: О грамматической основе речь. Подлежащее и сказуемое делают из набора слов предложение. Дайте фразу целиком. У вас и точки-то нет...

Comment: Цели высказывания нет. "В соответствии..." что случилось? "В соответствии с Вашим поручением в ходе визита о проведении капитального ремонта кровли в здании №5" выявились следующие проблемы:... или "Всё исполнено в соответствии с Вашим..." А запятые скорее всего не нужны, но цель указать-таки нужно.

Comment: в ходе визита о проведении капитального ремонта? Что за грамматика? Визит о чем?

Comment: ВИЗИТ, -а; м. [франц. visite]. Офиц. Кратковременное посещение кого-, чего-л. по долгу службы. Дружеский в. В. врача. В. вежливости. Нанести в. Отдать в. (устар.; совершить ответный визит). Прибыть с частным, государственным визитом (о главах государств, правительств и т.п.). / О любом посещении кого-л. кем-л. Отправиться с визитом к родственникам. //Ограниченная сочетаемость.